# SQL query using a function the argument of which is another query

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I would like to create a query using a function by passing an argument that comes from the result column of another table. Is it possible?

**Example**

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST."FUNCTION_1"(PARAM, '38622')
WHERE PARAM IN (
  SELECT "DocNum"
  FROM TEST."FUNCTION_2"('38622')
);
```

**Schema**: *TEST*

**Functions**:

- *FUNCTION_1*: Returns a table with values that are of interest and takes two arguments, the first of which is a unique ID that should come from another table.
- *FUNCTION_2*: Returns the column with the unique ID referenced by ***FUNCTION_1*** and takes one argument.

**PARAM**: The parameter in question, the value of which should change with the value of every different row returned from ***FUNCTION_2***.

**Desired result**: A table with the combined contents of *FUNCTION_1*'s results for every different "DocNum" returned by *FUNCTION_2*.

I am using DBeaver and am connected to a SAP/HANA database.